# Cannot able to call funtion/access variable from funtion components

Tags: reactjs

```
   Autoanimate = (props) => {
     const [margintop] = useState(new Animated.Value(50)) 

    const animate='hggfdfgsfds'
     return (
       <Animated.View              
         style={{
           ...props.style,
             marginTop: margintop,
                    // Bind opacity to animated value
         }}
       >
         {props.children}
       </Animated.View>
     );
    }


class some extends React.Component{
render(){

return(
<Text>{Autoanimate.animate}</Text>
)
}
}
```

This is not the original code by this is the code format

**What is expected**
text component will render the value from the function component

What has happened :
Value undefined

and also one more doubt, I cannot able to call the function inside that function component, why is that s so ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The nature of JavaScript is that you will not be able to access `animate` outside the `Autoanimate` function unless you explicitly expose it by `return`ing it. If you want to render the `Autoanimate` component itself, you can do so using JSX:

```
class some extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Text><Autoanimate style={{}} /></Text> 
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the alternate solution @Nick